# Is it possible to post form data to a specific function in a class file?

Tags: php

I have an index.php and a class controller.php
In the controller.php file I have a number of functions. Login, logout etc. However, when I post to the controller I cannot select the function I want. Do I have to create a separate file for each? i.e. login.php, logout.php etc? Or is there a way to send the post data to a specific function? I'm currently learning PHP so apologies if this is a noob question.

Comment: We have no idea why you would not be able to call a specific method.

Comment: can you give a code example of what you are talking about

Comment: dude whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttt?

Comment: I have a form. I post form to file.php in file.php are a number of functions. I wish to use just one of those functions based on input. It's really simple guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that if you tell your file which function you want to call. For example this form.

```
<form action="controller.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Now in your `controller.php`, you could do a specific action based on the `$_POST['action']`. In this case, call the login function.

```
if($_POST['action'] == "login")
    login();
```

You can also pass the $_POST data in your login function if your function accepts arguments.

```
function login(Array $data){
    // Whatever your code does
}

if($_POST['action'] == "login")
    login($_POST);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great but I made one modification

Comment: if($_POST){
    className::functionName();
  }